# Openwrt don't resolve hostnames to another Openwrt

Tags: openwrt

I have 2 Openwrt routers one is on front, another is on the back.

Back router's WAN connected to LAN of front router and have it's own subnet.
Back router WAN DNS configured to a front router.

Front router has several local DNS records in hostnames, but it doesn't resolve them for a back router.

Windows computer connected to a front router directly resolves those hostnames no problem.

Why front router do not resolve them for a back router?

Comment: Hi, does the back router NAT or don't ? Your setup is ususally done with the back router subnet route added the the front router. The front router reply ICMP redirect to any computer that want to talk to the other subnet. I suspect you double NAT, which will cause other problem.

Comment: @yagmoth555 yes they all NAT

Comment: How is name resolution configured on all implied systems?

Comment: @vidarlo It's dnsmasq on front router. I'm newby, I use Luci GUI

Comment: @Vladimir I don't think Serverfault is the right place for such an question; it's hardly about managing IT in a business environment. I'd suggest superuser.com - and include more information about your setup.

Comment: @yagmoth555 yes I think the problem is in double NAT, I will consider it, thank you.

Comment: @vidarlo yes I think you right I'm closing my question, thank you.

Comment: If you want to prevent the double NAT to optimize your network it's a discussion we can have too I dont mind, we can use the chat channel of the site as it's out of scope of the questions.